# Where is file ini_set in windows 10 i why have error in this script

Tags: php, laragon

What does ini_set do in this php code?

```
if ( ini_set( 'display_error', '1' ) === false )
    throw new \Exception( 'Unable to set display_errors.' );
```

Please help me run this code and display error I use laragon and it's not working

Comment: `ini_set` is a function that amends runtime parameters its not a file

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"? What happens when you run this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it will set the value of a configuration option of the `php.ini` file

[reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php)

in your case, it will turn on the display error in PHP code, so if you have an error, PHP will display it to you

instead of `display_error` you should put `display_errors`

`ini_set` is a function to change `php.ini` settings

you can change your `php.ini` settings like this image:

[image]